# VBA Excel - Generate real random numbers that check if result exist in given range

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am using following function to create random number and check if the resulting integer is in a given range:

```
Function RandBetweenInt(Lowest As Long, Highest As Long, Exclude As Range) As Long
  Dim R As Long
  Dim C As Range

  Do
    R = Lowest + Int(Rnd() * (Highest + 1 - Lowest))
    For Each C In Exclude
      If R = C Then Exit For
    Next C
  Loop Until C Is Nothing

  RandBetweenInt = R
  Application.Volatile
End Function
```

After calling the function `RandBetweenInt(0, 999, tgt.Range("K1:K1000"))` the result is correct, but I see that the resulting number is always the same (f.i 705) if I just close the file and open it again, so there is no a real random generation happening. Even if I create consecutive random numbers, the sequence seems to be always the same (705, 332, 107...).

For me is really important that each time I create the random number the result is really random. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Call `Randomize` once at the top of the function.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! Can you create a fast answer so I can accept it?

Comment: "not a real random generation happening"... Hard to achieve on a computer. ;)

Comment: @VincentG True, but we all know that what he meant was "generation of a new pseudo-random number"

Comment: Doing a linear search over `Exclude` in each pass through the main loop is inefficient. Instead, create a dictionary of distinct values in `Exclude` before you enter the main loop. The run time should noticeably improve.